# Image blur optimized for large areas of same color

Tags: java, graphics

I'm working on generating a drop shadow for a solid (but not rectangular) object. The input is a grayscale image that represents the opacity of the object. I then want to blur this, color it, and draw it behind the object.

Most frequently, this image will have large contiguous areas of the same shade, meaning that if I do a standard blur algorithm, I'm wasting cycles for the vast majority of the image. Consider the input and output below:

[image: input] [image: output]

All of the blurring work needs to happen at the edges, but the work on the large flat areas is just wasted, and represents well over 90% of the pixels.

Is there a common algorithm for blurring this kind of image that's substantially faster than blurring an arbitrary input image? The final code will be part of a Java application executed in an environment where GPU hardware is unavailable.

Comment: If you don't know ahead of time where the "interesting" bits of the image are, then you'll need to look for them.  I'd wager that calculating whether you should perform a blur on a particular pixel is almost as much work as actually applying the blur itself.  And for a large enough image, this is probably all going to be dominated by cache performance anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a specific algorithm available for this.  Because the image is monochrome, it may be relatively simple to implement a line-scanning algorithm in 2 passes (horizontal and vertical) that detects transitions, and having found a transition applies a blur at that point.

You might be able to, for example, scan every third row (and column), and at transitions apply a blur of radius 3.  You could play with the interval/radius to find an optimal balance.  Or, on the horizontal pass only apply a horizontal blur, and similarly on the vertical pass apply a vertical blur.

Or, you might forgo that approach all together, and look at a non-gaussian blur such as a 2-pass 1-dimensional orthogonal convolution filter.  According to the [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/) page on their blur operator, the speed of a simple convolution filter can be a factor of 10 or greater faster than a gaussian-based one.  The 2-pass 1-dimensional convolution filter is doing something similar to the line-scanning above (by performing a horizontal and vertical pass), but it applies across the image (even the solid areas).  But combining the "edge detection" with the orthogonal blur, you might be able to achieve significant speed-up.  Though in order to not confuse the algorithm, the image that is scanned should not be modified in-place but rather a second "destination" image should be modified.